# How to avoid splitting cultures in Google analytics

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics, globalization

I have MVC site, two cultures are supported: en-GB and no (Norway).
I use ControllerHelper, which has "en-GB" and "no" variables, putting them into URL (first one is default).
What disturbes me is that Google analytics for some reason splits visitors in such way:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w13q4gpvrb42nhm/GoogleAnalyticsSplitsCulture.png?dl=0

First of all, I wonder where "en-US" and "nb-NO" come from? I work via CultureHelper, "default culture" method returns me first variable ("en-GB"), not "en-US", it is used in RouteConfig.cs... Maybe no one would ever give me some hints.. Though, I do not have problem with site, which would give me some idea.

What I want is to use /en (GB region) and /no everywhere and make sure Google analytics merges all data for en and no users.

Comment: That's the language configured in the users' browser. Not really helpful, but no reason to worry either.

Comment: Hmm... do you mean that I cannot influence on that and just treat all "en" users as english users without splitting them in statistics?

Comment: GA collects the language setting from the user agent, there is no useful way to influence that. However the language of the browser is not necessarily the language of the user (e.g. I am german but my browser is set to english) so you should take that info with a grain of salt.